# EFVI library openonload-201509-u1 checksum comparsion

Tags: checksum, openonload

I am using EFVI library openonload-201509-u1. 
I am running an efvi 6 binary which listens to a udp multicast feed.
I do not believe any 'checksum comparsion' is used to check for corruption of received packets. Is anyone able to provide proof that no checksum comparsion is being used, and possibly suggest any way of 'switching on' this check?

Thanks